# Showing parent and child in one row

Tags: laravel, html-table, bootstrap-4

actually I have a table in a laravel website with data from diffrent joined database tables. But this way I get a row for every child and recurring parent data.

Instead I'd like to have one row per parent data and all childs in the same row.

Looks like a basic problem, but actually I've lost sight.

Any idea?

View:

```
    $rechnungen=DB::select(DB::raw("
    select
    reintern, krenr, krebez, bnrkenn, bubelegnr, aufnr, sacktonr, sacbez, ustkenn,
    TO_CHAR(round(bupbetr*(1+ustproz/100),2), '99G999D99', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = '',.') as brutto,
    wiebez, objktext, vektext
    from RECHNUNG re
    join BUCHUNG bu on bu.REKEY=re.REKEY
    ...
    join BUCHUNGPOS bup on bup.BUKEY=bu.BUKEY and nvl(BUPARTKZ,0)=0 and bup.KREKEY is null
   ...
    where re_status=0
    order by bnr.BNRKENN, bu.BUBELEGNR
    "));
```

Controller:

```
               @foreach ($rechnungen as $re)
                <tr>
                  <td></td>
                  <td>{{$re->wiebez}} {{$re->objktext}} {{$re->ve_ktext}}</td>
                  <td>{{$re->krektonr}}</td>
                  <td>{{$re->krebez}}</td>
                  <td>{{$re->bnrkenn}} {{$re->bubelegnr}}</td>
                  <td>{{$re->aufnr}}</td>
                  <td>{{$re->sacktonr}} {{$re->sacbez}}</td>
                  <td class="text-right">{{$re->ust_kenn}}</td>
                  <td class="text-right">{{$re->brutto}} €</td>
                </tr>
                @endforeach
```

Comment: Would you be able to show your current code

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you just need to create a relation *Many To Many* https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: I'm not trying to create a new model. It's already there. I'm just trying to show data in a table.

Comment: I suggest you the right way. You must create a model for the parent table, a model for the child table, and create a one-to-many relationship. I do not recommend using pure sql for such simple queries in Laravel.

Comment: Serhii is, of course, correct. Your model code becomes much simpler if you implement separate models for BILLs and BOOKINGs, then link them with a one-many relationship. In your view, you then iterate over BILLS, starting a new row for each, and inside that loop, you iterate over BOOKINGs, displaying data for each in a separate cell. This would be cleaner than my solution, which assumes you do not change the model.

Answer (score 0):

In an attempt to understand your issue in English:

You appear to have 3 tables:

```
Table BILL: Columns REKEY + various data
Table BOOKING: Columns BUKEY + REKEY + various data
Table BOOKINGPOS: Columns BUPKEY + BUKEY + various data
```

Where BOOKING.REKEY is a foreign key reference to BILL.REKEY and BOOKINGPOS.BUKEY is a foreign key reference to BOOKING.BUKEY.

I assume that each BILL can have multiple BOOKINGs and each BOOKING can have multiple BOOKINGPOSs.

The problem you are having is a display/view issue, not a data/model issue.  In pseudo-code, you should implement your view as follows:

```
{{ $last_rekey="" }}
@foreach( $rows as $row )
  @if( $row->rekey != $last_rekey )
    @if( $last_rekey != "" )
      </tr>
    @endif
    <tr>
      <td>$row->BILLdata1</td>
      <td>$row->BILLdata2</td>
      ...
    $last_rekey=$row->rekey
  @endif
  <td>$row->BOOKINGdata1</td>
  <td>$row->BOOKINGdata2</td>
  ...
  <td>$row->BOOKINGPOSdata1</td>
  ...
@endforeach
</tr>
```

The idea being that whenever a row of data contains a new BILL, you start displaying a new row in the table, otherwise, you just continue adding cells to the current row.